# A blocking but non-modal QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, qdialog, qmessagebox

I have a stack of images on which I want to perform some operations. After processing each image, my program should pop up a dialog to prompt the user if they want to proceed with the next image or to abort. Before that, they should have an opportunity to do some manual changes either on the images or on the parameters. Anyway, they must have access to the windows of the applications, while the execution of the method that called the dialog should be blocked until the dialog is closed.

I tried to solve this with a QMessageBox, but if I open it via exec(), it blocks the entire application, and if I use show(), the execution of the program goes on without waiting for user's reaction.

Is there a convenient way to block the calling method or function with a dialog but permit the user to interact with other windows?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: You could create a new window which you can show as modal.  and let the user perform the image manipulation in that window instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should split your method that you want to block into two parts. In the end of first part you need to show your dialog without blocking and connect "Next" button (for example) of the dialog to the slot that must contains second part of your old method. This slot will be executed only when user presses the button.

It's the right way to do it in Qt. You need posibly to change your code logic to implement this.

Also, do you really need the second dialog? You can place "Next" button to your main widget. You can also create another modal dialog that will contain some settings and "Next" button.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I have moved the contents of the for-loop into a separate method and created a subclass of QMessageWnd to store all formerly local variables (or pointers to the respective data) that I need to keep across all images during processing.